# Prove that the series $ \sum v_n $ converges, with: $ v_n = \frac{\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}}{ n!} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> We have $ a_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} - \ln(n) $ converges to Euler constant $ \gamma $

> Prove that the series $ \sum v_n $ converges, with: $ v_n = \frac{\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}}{ n!} $

---

Using the ratio test, we have:

$$ \frac{v_{n + 1}}{v_n} = \frac{1}{n+1}.\frac{a_{n+1} + \ln(n+1)}{a_{n} + \ln(n)} $$

How to proceed to prove that the series converges?

Comment: Hint: for $n\geq 1$, $$
\left| {v_n } \right| = \frac{1}{{n!}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  \le \frac{1}{{n!}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n 1  = \frac{1}{{n!}}n = \frac{1}{{(n - 1)!}}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first satement shows that $v_n <\frac { C+\ln n} {n!}$ for some constant $C$. Now show that $\sum \frac { C+\ln n} {n!}$ is convergent using ratio test.

Comment: Do you mean by the constant $C$ the limit of the sequence $(a_n)$ ?

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi Any convergent sequence is bounded. So $(a_n)$ is bounded by some constant $C$.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is large enough, then $\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\log(n)-\gamma\right|<1$, and therefore$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k<\log(n)+\gamma+1<n+\gamma+1.$$So, since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+\gamma+1}{n!}$ converges (by the ratio test, for instance), so does your series.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  \le \sum_{k = 1}^n 1  = n$.

Comment: @Gary Yes, that simplifies things. It did not occur to me.